# Revisiting TIPA and Fontspec

Tags: errors, fontspec, debugging, tipa

`fontspec` does not generally play nicely with `TIPA` these days. My intention in this question is to find out what exactly is causing the problem.

In attempting to diagnose the problem, I began with the following, simple MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} %no-math option provided to remove guff
                               %from the log file

\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\textipa[2][r]{{\fontfamily{cm#1}\tipaencoding #2}}
}
\renewenvironment{IPA}[1][r]{\fontfamily{cm#1}\tipaencoding}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{IPA}
  kAT
\end{IPA}

\end{document}
```

This, to my surprise, is an MWE that actually works, it does exactly what it should do.

Introducing an accent, however, breaks things. This:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} %no-math option provided to remove guff
                               %from the log file

\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\textipa[2][r]{{\fontfamily{cm#1}\tipaencoding #2}}
}
\renewenvironment{IPA}[1][r]{\fontfamily{cm#1}\tipaencoding}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{IPA}
  kAT\'{a}
\end{IPA}

\end{document}
```

Won't compile. And when I say, "won't compile," `xelatex` does not terminate, but it does use up 100% CPU and my laptop fan starts. Eventually, I am forced to interrupt with Ctrl-c. What follows are the final lines printed on my terminal:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(./TIPA_Experiment.aux) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
^C! Interruption.
\reserved@c ->\tipaupperaccent 
                               {1}
l.19   kAT\'{
             a}
?
```

And this is the final 15%, or so, of the `.log` file:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(./TIPA_Experiment.aux)
\openout1 = `TIPA_Experiment.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 16.
 (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(51.21504pt, 495.07779pt, 51.21504pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(51.21504pt, 742.61676pt, 51.21504pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=495.07779pt
* \textheight=742.61676pt
* \oddsidemargin=-21.05495pt
* \evensidemargin=-21.05495pt
* \topmargin=-58.05495pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=44.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

! Interruption.
\reserved@c ->\tipaupperaccent 
                               {1}
l.19   kAT\'{
             a}
? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14318 strings out of 493918
 287219 string characters out of 6150563
 322624 words of memory out of 5000000
 17533 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 5735 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1144 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 46i,1n,35p,10393b,95s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

This doesn't actually help me to understand what's going wrong.

I should also point out that exactly what is printed seems to vary. On one occasion (after actually leaving it for quite a long while) the `.log` file finished here:

```
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocol
```

And then the `! Interruption` stuff was printed beneath.

(I may have mistaken exactly where `\@twocolumnfalse` was truncated, I didn't copy it at the time).

Another example of terminal output is:

```
^C! Interruption.
\new@ifnextchar ...rved@a {#2}\def \reserved@b {#3
                                                  }\futurelet \@let@token \n...
l.19   kAT\'{
             a}
?
```

So: What is the nature of this problem?

Comment: Just as a heads up, in a future version of fontspec the xunicode package will no longer be loaded automatically. Some accent commands etc. will be supported but no TIPA.

Answer (score 6):

The Latin Modern fonts don't support IPA, but trying to load the legacy fonts is hopeless.

Since `\textipa` is available with `fontspec`, one just modifies it in order to use a font supporting IPA (in this case CMU Serif).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\tipacm}[Scale=MatchUppercase]{CMU Serif}

\NewEnviron{IPA}{\expandafter\textipa\expandafter{\BODY}}
\renewcommand\useTIPAfont{\tipacm}% thanks to Ulrike

\begin{document}

\textipa{k\textscripta T\'{a}}

\textipa{kAT\'{a}}

\begin{IPA}
  kAT\'{a}
\end{IPA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can set the font with `\renewcommand\useTIPAfont{\tipacm}`. There is no need to patch `\textipa`.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes a lot of sense +1. But, would it be possible to explain why it is hopeless? Also, is this the only work around? (It seems like it's quite a good one if it is, but is there any way to special case `TIPA` so that `fontspec` doesn't interfere with it?)

Comment: @Au101 `fontspec`, via `xunicode`, wants to provide support for IPA, so going back to support the legacy `tipa` package becomes, at least, very difficult. And in my opinion there's no point in doing this: as you see, the input is the same as with `tipa` and it works. You can also directly use the Unicode characters in the IPA range: try `\textipa{kɑθá}`.

Comment: Fair enough, so CMU Serif is one of the Computer Modern Unicode fonts? Is there a difference between this and the old style? Anyway, I thank you :) Would you, though, be able to explain what's broken? Just for my own personal understanding - not to solve any problem or anything. I'm just interested to know where the conflict lies and why exactly `TIPA` and `fontspec` cannot play together where once they did. What exactly is the problem? From a purely academic point of view

Comment: @Au101 By default, `fontspec` uses Latin Modern, that has optical sizes, whereas CMU Serif has just one size that's scaled; it's not really a big deal, since IPA insertions are distinct anyway; you can also set CMU Serif as default, if you want: it supports Latin, Greek, Cyrillic and IPA.