# Fontspec and tipa works together...just not on overleaf

Tags: fontspec, overleaf, tipa

I'm attempting to use Tipa with fontspec. I realize there are several posts on SE saying that it won't work or it can't be done. The thing is, I a have document that compiles and works well enough when I compile it locally with texlive. It gives me some warnings, but as I said it works. However, running the same document in overleaf omits the tipa characters. Anyway this could work (even with warnings) on overleaf?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
bla bla  /l\textscripta :k/ bla bla /l\textscripta :g/ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the easy alternative of Unicode input and a matching font?

Comment: Yes I could and I might just end up doing that. First, I would have to rewrite many examples throughout a fairly long document. Second, I was also a bit curios as to why It would work on my local installation but not on overleaf

Comment: It may be due to an older version of `tipa.sty` and/or xelatex on Overleaf... for now, if you add `\newfontfamily{\tipacm}[Scale=MatchUppercase]{CMU Serif}
\renewcommand\useTIPAfont{\tipacm}` to your preamble (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273508/226), and then write `\textipa{/lA:k/}` or `\textipa{/l\textscripta :k/}`, it should then work. Example: https://www.overleaf.com/read/sjzrvcwqrrxk Sorry for the inconvenience! :-|

Comment: The exact behaviour of your example depends on the fontspec/latex version, more precisely if fontspec loads xunicode (older system) or not (newer system).  With xunicode you need a open type font that has the chars, e.g. with `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` it would work. Without xunicode type symbols falls back to the old type1 fonts.

Comment: @LarsChristianJensen If you haven't rewritten your entire code and want to have Unicode output with the same `tipa` input; try the new [`tipauni`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipauni) package.